# Joining 3 tables doesnt work, should I use a subquery for the below

Tags: oracle

I have this query.

```
SELECT re_current_benefits.prospect_nbr, qo_quote.quote_id, hra_ind, quote_type, effective_date, quote_expiration_ind, mhs_lob_code
FROM re_current_benefits
INNER JOIN qo_quote ON qo_quote.prospect_nbr = re_current_benefits.prospect_nbr
WHERE hra_ind = 'Y' AND quote_type = 'R' AND quote_expiration_ind IS NULL AND mhs_lob_code NOT IN 'DTL1' AND mhs_lob_code NOT IN 'DTL2'
```

And I need to pull the prospect_nbr from here, I also need to add a filter saying effective_date = renewal_date but if I do that by joining all 3 tables together I get 0 results which should not be the case.

```
SELECT prospect_nbr, rmr_run_status, renewal_date
FROM re_group
WHERE rmr_run_status = ANY ('S', 'W')
```

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: SELECT re_group.prospect_nbr, re_current_benefits.quote_id, hra_ind, rmr_run_status, effective_date, renewal_date, quote_type, quote_expiration_ind, mhs_lob_code
FROM re_group
INNER JOIN qo_quote ON qo_quote.prospect_nbr = re_group.prospect_nbr INNER JOIN re_current_benefits ON re_current_benefits.prospect_nbr = re_group.prospect_nbr
WHERE hra_ind = 'Y' AND rmr_run_status = ANY ('S', 'W') AND quote_type = 'R' AND quote_expiration_ind IS NULL AND mhs_lob_code NOT IN 'DTL1' AND mhs_lob_code NOT IN 'DTL2' AND effective_date = renewal_date

Comment: Add aliases to *all* columns in your query

Comment: how does that help?